# How to do slicing on list which is constructed by string

Tags: python-3.x

```
    mylist=[]
    servername ='Ldn1zom2,ldn1zom3,ldn1zom4'
    mylist.append(servername)
    print(len(mylist))
```

Hey Please have a look on that piece of code above 
 i am trying to construct a list from a given string using .append() method
 while i am slice and printing their length it should give output 3 but it is giving 1 can you explain why list element showing as a 1 not 3

Answer (score 0):

You get the length `1` because you append *one string*.

First of all the `append` function appends a *single element*. You need to *`extend`* the list instead.

Secondly `servername` is a single string not a list in itself. You need to [*`split`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) the string.

All in all you need to do e.g.

```
mylist.extend(servername.split(','))
```

---

Or considering that you start out with an empty list in the example, just initialize the list with the splitted string:

```
mylist = servername.split(',')
```

You only need to `extend` the list if it's non-empty and you want to keep the existing elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are only having 1 as the length of your list is because you are appending a one whole string.

If you wish to split them use the string split function instead, example:

```
mylist = servername.split(',')
print(len(mylist))
```

More on string split function: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_split.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are getting length 1 because you have inserted the entire string in list

If you want to split on comma(,)

```
servername ='Ldn1zom2,ldn1zom3,ldn1zom4'
mylist = servername.split(',')
print(len(mylist))
```

split function return list of items

or 
if you want to slice string on based of start-index and end-index

```
mylist = []
servername ='Ldn1zom2,ldn1zom3,ldn1zom4'
item1 = servername[0:8]
mylist.append(item1)
item2 = servername[9:17]
mylist.append(item2)
item3 = servername[18:]
mylist.append(item3)
print(len(mylist))
```